# Test android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN in device farms

Tags: android, mdm, aws-device-farm

I am looking for a device farm, where it's possbile to test an android application that requires the permission for device administration (android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN)

Does anyone know such a device farm? I also appreciate any different ideas on how to automate a wide test with this permission required. btw. AWS doesnt support this feature.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for AWS Device Farm. This feature is not supported for public devices due to challenges with app removal after test execution. However, this feature is supported for private devices. The official FAQ has more information about private devices if you're interested: https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but why you just dont open a new VM or any kind of sandboxing for the public devices? would be better for all kind of customers